# Two async tasks sharing a global property

Tags: objective-c, bolts-framework

I have a toy problem where I have two method calls A and B. They both make API calls and both have success callback blocks. Method A populates a property in the controller and method B reads it and does some computations with it in the success block after method B's api request finishes. Now I can't just execute both of these like:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *test;

[self methodA];
[self methodB];
```

The callback from B might happen before the callback from A and B would end up reading an empty property. I was looking into the Bolts framework and was wondering if anyone here can give some pointers on how to use it to achieve this? Essentially I only want the api calls to happen asynchronously and then B should wait till A finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an external framework for such a task, just use a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). GCD provides semaphores, see [`dispatch_semaphore_create` and friends](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_semaphore_create.3.html).

Adapting the first example from that reference, in pseudo-code you will have something like:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *test;

sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[self methodA]; 
[self methodB];

- (void) methodA
{
   ...
   // set test
   dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
   ...
}

- (void) methodB
{
   ...
   // prepare to read test
   dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema);
   // read test
   ...
}
```

HTH